# std::string and placeholders

Tags: c++, string

Hi I would like to construct a string something like this

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::string str = "Proc.Status_1.power";

//code here that allows me to replace place holder _1 with a number dynamically
```

Is there any way in C++ to do this kind of string manipulation. if not is there any other easier alternative.

I have several such strings, I would like to keep in an unordred_map and fetch them at run time and insert required number to replace the place holders.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at boost format library?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace

Answer (score 4):

That's not how placeholders work. [The placeholders like `_1` etc.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) are currently only used as placeholder arguments for [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

If you want to format a string either use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) if you have access to it, [the format library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) that `std::format` is based on, or [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to construct your string.

So either

```
auto str = std::format("Proc.Status{}.power", some_value);
```

Or

```
// Using the format library linked to above
auto str = fmt::format("Proc.Status{}.power", some_value);
```

Or

```
auto str = (std::ostringstream() << "Proc.Status" << some_value << ".power").str();
```

Comment: Thanks, std::format is useful in my case.

Comment: @cpp_hex ...and put in an `unordered_map` you could do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke34Kv4q4)